# Successive submit of my ajax form still give me the same data in my action controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use an ajax form for removing items from a list. The first time I submit something, it works but the second times, the reference of the item submitted is not correct: it is the first reference that is still used.

Here is my ajax form:

```
<div>
    <table>            
        @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectTechnology)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.TechnologyID) </td>
                <td>@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RemoveLinkedTechnology", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "AddedTechnologies" })) { 
                    @Html.Hidden("projectID", item.ProjectID) 
                    @Html.Hidden("removedTechnologyID", item.TechnologyID) 
                    <input type="submit" value="Suppr" /> 
                    }</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the action in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveLinkedTechnology(int projectID, string removedTechnologyID)
    {
         // some code here...
    }
```

Example:

Lets say I proceed the submitting like this: first submit: AA; second submit: BB.

For the first call: removedTechnologyID contains AA.

For the second call: removedTechnologyID still contains AA.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: How many forms do you have in your submissions? Assuming you have 2 or more (through your iteration), your changes are always in the same form, for instance, in the first one?

Comment: Could you post a rendered html snippet with at least two remove forms on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that in your controller action you are returning a partial view which updates the contents of the `<table>` you have shown. Now since Html helpers such as Hidden or TextBox first look for values in ModelState before binding and then in the model what happens is that `@Html.Hidden("removedTechnologyID", item.TechnologyID)` sees that there is a `removedTechnologyID="AA"` in the model state and completely ignores your model value which is `item.TechnologyID`. So if you have looked at the DOM after the first AJAX request you would have seen that all hidden fields have the old values inside them.

To fix this you have 3 possibilities:

1. Clear the item in model state in your controller action:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult RemoveLinkedTechnology(int projectID, string removedTechnologyID)
   {
       ...
       ModelState.Remove("removedTechnologyID");
       ModelState.Remove("projectID");
       return View(...);
   }
   ```
2. Don't use helpers to generate the hidden fields:

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="projectID" value="@item.ProjectID" />
   <input type="hidden" name="removedTechnologyID" value="@item.TechnologyID" />
   ```
3. Write a custom `Html.Hidden` helper which will first use the values in the model before looking at modelstate (out of scope for this answer)